# Скрытие блока при нажатии вне его, либо свайпом вправо

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята подскажите как скрывать блок при нажатии вне его, а то на данный момент блок открывается и закрывается нажатием на кнопку "Наши услуги".

Либо может сделать скрытие на мобильных устройствах просто свайпом вправо?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно добавить следующее событие: при нажатии на документ - проверяете, нажато ли на нужный вам блок, если нет - скрываете его.

```js
$(document).on('click', function(e){
  if (!$('.window').is(e.target)){
    $('.window').animate({opacity: 0}, 500);
  }
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background:blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:flex-start;
}

.window{
  width:100px;
  height:200px;  
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="window"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вставил скрипт, присвоил класс своего блока.

В итоге при нажатии на кнопку "Наши услуги" сразу на доли секунды выходит меню и сразу скрывается , а потом до обновления страницы вообще кнопка становиться не активна